# tsql best way to merge records with start date and end date when there is no gap in between

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a mapping table as follows :

```
FirstEntityID int
MappedTo int
BeginDate Date
EndDate Date
```

and lets say I have following records in the table :

```
FirstEntityID  MappedTo  BeginDate     EndDate 
     1             2     2012-09-01   2012-10-01
     2             3     2012-09-01   2012-10-01
     1             2     2012-10-02   2012-11-24
     2             3     2012-11-01   2012-11-24
```

I need a script which will get this table and merges records based on the Start and end date to return a result like :

```
   FirstEntityID  MappedTo  BeginDate     EndDate 
     1             2     2012-09-01   2012-11-24
     2             3     2012-09-01   2012-10-01
     2             3     2012-11-01   2012-11-24
```

Comment: Can't see the logic on how that went from 4 rows to 3 rows.

Comment: @Blam the record with firstEntityID = 1 and mappedTo = 2 has repeated but continuing from the first record end date with no gap

Comment: And we are supposed to get that from "merges records based on the Start and end date"?  What if there was a third 1 2 that did not overlap?

Comment: @Blam I thought the example will explain what I mean together with the title but sorry if it didn't ! in case of third one which does not overlap we'll keep it as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CTEs, we find the starting dates first:

```
; WITH StartD AS
  ( SELECT 
        FirstEntityID
      , MappedTo
      , BeginDate
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY FirstEntityID, MappedTo
                           ORDER BY BeginDate )
          AS Rn 
    FROM
        tableX AS t
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM tableX AS p
          WHERE p.FirstEntityID = t.FirstEntityID
            AND p.MappedTo = t.MappedTo
            AND p.BeginDate < t.BeginDate 
            AND t.BeginDate <= DATEADD(day, 1, p.EndDate)
        )
  )
```

then the ending dates:

```
, EndD AS
  ( SELECT 
        FirstEntityID
      , MappedTo
      , EndDate
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY FirstEntityID, MappedTo
                           ORDER BY EndDate )
          AS Rn 
    FROM
        tableX AS t
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM tableX AS p
          WHERE p.FirstEntityID = t.FirstEntityID
            AND p.MappedTo = t.MappedTo
            AND DATEADD(day, -1, p.BeginDate) <= t.EndDate
            AND t.EndDate < p.EndDate
        )
  )
```

and the final result:

```
SELECT
    s.FirstEntityID
  , s.MappedTo
  , s.BeginDate
  , e.EndDate
FROM
    StartD AS s
  JOIN
    EndD AS e
      ON  e.FirstEntityID = s.FirstEntityID
      AND e.MappedTo = s.MappedTo
      AND e.Rn = s.Rn ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76878/10)**

Comment: hi, thanks. just one clarification : as you can see in my example the end date for 1 to 2 has been updated but it doesn't work like that with your code. is it possible to modify it ?

Comment: +1  On a duplicate row it seems to reported both when I tested.

Comment: @Blam: Thnx, you are right. I assumed that `(FirstEntityID, MappedTo, BeginDate)` will be unique. If not, a `GROUP BY` (by those 3 columns) has to be added in both CTEs.

Comment: SQLFiddle does not seem to be working correctly. Any chance you could post the amended code here as this querie is exactly what I need. Thank very much...

Comment: @Killercam can you explain what you mean with "amended code"? This is quite old question.

Comment: @Killercam and besides that, the code provided in the answer works fine, just used it

Answer (score 1):

Tested this and it seems to work

It will fail on an edge case with duplicate rows.
For that would need to go with a RowNumber approach like Ypercube.
Or add a constraint on the table to force the row to be unique.

```
-- first the overlaps
SELECT T1.FirstEntityId, T1.MappedTo, T1.BeginDate, Max(T2.EndDate) as [EndDate]
FROM tablex as T1
join tablex as T2  
  on  T1.FirstEntityId = T2.FirstEntityId
  and T1.MappedTo = T2.MappedTo
  and T1.EndDate >= T2.BeginDate 
  and T1.EndDate <  T2.EndDate
  and T1.BeginDate <= T2.BeginDate
GROUP BY T1.FirstEntityId, T1.MappedTo, T1.BeginDate  

union

-- add the non overlaps
SELECT T1.FirstEntityId, T1.MappedTo, T1.BeginDate, T1.EndDate
FROM tablex as T1
join tablex as T2  
  on  T1.FirstEntityId = T2.FirstEntityId
  and T1.MappedTo = T2.MappedTo
  and (  T1.EndDate  < T2.BeginDate or T1.BeginDate > T2.EndDate 
   or   (T1.BeginDate  < T2.BeginDate and T1.EndDate > T2.EndDate) )

order by FirstEntityId, MappedTo, BeginDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
SELECT FirstEntityId, MappedTo, Min(BeginDate), Max(EndDate)
FROM
    T1
GROUP BY
    FirstEntityId, MappedTo
```